# MySQL procedure with complex SELECT gives "Undeclared Variable" on table names

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, procedure

I'm trying to create my first set of MySQL procedures. In this case, I want to have a simple call collate relevant information from 4 tables into a single result and return a discrete selection of fields as the result. To this end, I've written this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DatabaseName.GetCityIdentity`
( 
IN  CityId BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
OUT
    `id`            BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `provId`        BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `countryId`     BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `currencyId`    BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `cityName`      VARCHAR(64),
    `latitude`      DECIMAL(10,6),
    `longitude`     DECIMAL(10,6),
    `provName`      VARCHAR(64),
    `provAbbr`      VARCHAR(4),
    `countryName`   VARCHAR(64),
    `countryAbbr`   VARCHAR(4),
    `currencyName`  VARCHAR(64),
    `currencySymbol`VARCHAR(8),
    `fullName`      VARCHAR(256),
    `abbrName`      VARCHAR(80)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        `c`.`id` INTO `id`, `c`.`name` INTO `cityName`, `c`.`provId` INTO `provId`, `c`.`latitude` INTO`latitude`, `c`.`longitude` INTO `longitude`,
        `p`.`name` INTO `provName`, `p`.`abbr` INTO `provAbbr`, `p`.`countryId` INTO `countryId`,
        `y`.`name` INTO `countryName`, `y`.`abbr` INTO `countryAbbr`, `y`.`defaultCurrency` INTO `currencyId`,
        `d`.`name` INTO `currencyName`, `d`.`symbol` INTO `currencySymbol`,
        CONCAT(`c`.`name`, ', ', `p`.`name`, ', ', `y`.`Name`) INTO `fullName`,
        CONCAT(`c`.`name`, ', ', `p`.`abbr`, ', ', `y`.`abbr`) INTO `abbrName`
    FROM `cities` AS `c`
        LEFT JOIN `provinces` AS `p` ON `c`.`provId` = `p`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `y` ON `p`.`countryId` = `y`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `currencies` AS `d` ON `y`.`defaultCurrency` = `d`.`id`
    WHERE (`c`.`id` = CityId) LIMIT 1
END;
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting errors on the Table names in the `SELECT` query ("Error: 1327: Undeclared variable: c"). So how am I supposed to build this `SELECT` such that it works as intended, without referencing the table names?

I tried removing all the "AS `x`" statements, and using just the actual table names instead, but, of course, I get the exact same error, just with the variable name replaced by the table name...

I'm sure that this is an obvious/simple thing to a regular (My)SQL developer, but it seems extraordinarily contra-intuitive to me so far..

PS: If it matters, I'm using MySQL Workbench to do this.

Comment: See correct syntax at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your syntax is incorrect; please try placing the INTO below the select as follows;

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `DatabaseName.GetCityIdentity`
(
IN  CityId bigint(20) unsigned,
OUT
    `id`            BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `provId`        BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `countryId`     BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `currencyId`    BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
    `cityName`      VARCHAR(64),
    `latitude`      DECIMAL(10,6),
    `longitude`     DECIMAL(10,6),
    `provName`      VARCHAR(64),
    `provAbbr`      VARCHAR(4),
    `countryName`   VARCHAR(64),
    `countryAbbr`   VARCHAR(4),
    `currencyName`  VARCHAR(64),
    `currencySymbol`VARCHAR(8),
    `fullName`      VARCHAR(256),
    `abbrName`      VARCHAR(80)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        `cities`.`id`,
        `cities`.`name`,
        `cities`.`provId`,
        `cities`.`latitude`,
        `cities`.`longitude`,
        `provinces`.`name`,
        `provinces`.`abbr`,
        `provinces`.`countryId`,
        `countries`.`name`,
        `countries`.`abbr`,
        `countries`.`defaultCurrency`,
        `currencies`.`name`,
        `currencies`.`symbol`,
        CONCAT(`cities`.`name`, ', ', `provinces`.`name`, ', ', `country`.`Name`),
        CONCAT(`cities`.`name`, ', ', `provinces`.`abbr`, ', ', `country`.`abbr`)
    INTO `id`, `cityName`, `provId`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `provName`, 
          `provAbbr`, `countryId`, `countryName`, `countryAbbr`, 
          `currencyId`, `currencyName`, `currencySymbol`, `fullName`,
          `abbrName`
    FROM `cities`
        LEFT JOIN `provinces` ON `cities`.`provId` = `provinces`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `provinces`.`countryId` = `countries`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `currencies` ON `countries`.`defaultCurrency` = `currencies`.`id`
    WHERE (`cities`.`id` = CityId) LIMIT 1;
END // 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Okay, so when I call this with a city record id number as the parameter, I get "Incorrect Number of Parameters"? How do I do this so that calling it returns the collection of fields that I'm looking for as though I'd executed the `SELECT` statement directly?

I just want to be able to use something like `CALL GetCityIdentity(1);` and get back a result identical to having just issued that huge `SELECT` statement...

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this. Is this something where a `VIEW` would work better?

The point is that there are a number of times where a table is queried that has a reference to a `Cities.Id` record and I'm looking for a shortcut way to retrieve these fields without having to add all of that query syntax to every query that cross references a city Id in another table...

Comment: Yes, I would use a view for this. Just remember you cannot update data explicitly through a view though.

Comment: You can select from a view ie SELECT * FROM vw_whatever WHERE city_id = 1 but you can't do UPDATE vw_whatever SET currency_symbol = '£' WHERE city_id = 1

Comment: Oic, np! -- this is strictly for pulling data, not for modifying anything. The issue was just having to add this huge amount of code to every `SELECT` where a city is referenced just to get some little piece of it. With this the hope is that it'll be a lot easier to just get whatever bit(s) of City info are needed. Thanks!